# Binding within DataTemplate does not work on first load of view

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have a dependency property on a custom control that I am trying to bind to a property in the view model.  The control is inside of a `DataTemplate` in the view (a `UserControl`).  However, the binding seems to only function if the binding characteristics are changed *after* the view loads.

So, here's an example of what's in the view's XAML:

```
<dxb:BarStaticItem Alignment="Far">
    <dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:AllMaxDateRangeCombo Grid.Row="1"
                                           DateRange="{Binding DataContext.WorkOrderDateRange, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                           TimeFrameType="Current"
                                           Width="150" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </dxb:BarStaticItem.ContentTemplate>
</dxb:BarStaticItem>
```

`BarStaticItem` is a DevExpress control used when putting "normal" controls in a toolbar.  The binding that I have defined in the `AllMaxDateRangeCombo` does not function when the view is first loaded.  But at runtime (during debug), if were to change the property name by adding a digit to the end of it, and then immediately removing that digit, the binding would then begin to work.

For lack of better understanding, I can only say that it seems like the binding is not being "hooked up" properly at first load, or that it tries before some piece of it is ready.  But then when I make a change at runtime, suddenly it's linked.

I hope this makes sense enough for someone to help me work out what is going on here.

P.S.:  using the Snoop tool, I can see that the control's dependency property `DateRange` has no binding on it at all until I make that runtime change.  Then, a binding appears.  So for whatever reason, the binding I have defined simply doesn't kick in at first load of the view.

EDIT:  in response to a question I'll explain a bit of the mechanics.  The `AllMaxDateRangeCombo` is basically a ComboBox with choices like LastMonth, Today, LastWeek, etc.  When a selection is made, the date range is recalculated and assigned to the control's `DateRange` dependency property.  Since that is the property I am trying to bind to, I expect the UI view model's property to change along with it.  Then I would respond and update UI data.  But that property value never changes.  Hence, either the binding is never really getting hooked up, or it is somehow unable to notify changes.

Comment: I dont know the solution but I will vote your question UP because I think it is a well explained one and I would like to know the solution too. PS: Can you upload the project or something like that (maybe on githiub)? It would be really nice if I could download it for debbuging. Best regards

Comment: @AdrianEfford Thank you.  Unfortunately, I cannot upload.  Partly because it's a huge project, but also because it is proprietary work.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: Are you saying that the `DateRange` property is not set intially? How did you confirm this? What's the value default of the `WorkOrderDateRange` source property? Are you sure it's not the same as the default value of `DateRange`?

Comment: @mm8 It gets a default, which is a Date Min/Max basically.  No, what I'm saying is that it appears that the binding just doesn't happen.  The control is combobox-like, and when a choice is made (e.g. LastMonth), the DateRange is set accordingly.  I am trying to respond to that change and update UI data, but my view model's property never changes, hence my belief that the binding isn't really hooking up.  Or at least it cannot notify for some reason.

Comment: @mm8 I added a better explanation to the question.  Let me know if there is more I can provide.

Comment: @mm8  Something else worth noting:  I used `PresentationTraceSources` to watch binding in both scenarios, and they were identical (initial load vs making the silly change).

Comment: @DonBoitnott: `DateRange` is the *target* property here and `WorkOrderDateRange` is the *source* property so you set the initial value using the `WorkOrderDateRange` property. Does that answer your question? In order to verify that the binding works, set a breakpoint in the getter of `WorkOrderDateRange`. It should get git when the view is loaded.

Comment: @mm8 And all of that I can verify.  The breakpoint does hit, and the initial value is set.  But changes to DateRange in the control's code do not propagate back down to WorkOrderDateRange.  It's a two-way binding.

Comment: @DonBoitnott: You need to provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this issue if you want anyone to be able to point out why then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being due to how the values in the control were being changed.  In the control, this dependency property was defined:

```
public static DependencyProperty DateRangeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DateRange", typeof(DateTimeRange), typeof(AllMaxDateRangeCombo), new PropertyMetadata(new DateTimeRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue)));
public DateTimeRange DateRange
{
    get => (DateTimeRange)GetValue(DateRangeProperty);
    set => SetValue(DateRangeProperty, value);
}
```

After the combo box selection changed, that value was being set:

```
private void RecalculateDates()
{
    DateRange = new DateTimeRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue);
}
```

That worked fine in a two-way binding so long as the usage of the control was not in a `DataTemplate`.  But once it was used in a `DataTemplate`, then only this version works:

```
SetCurrentValue(DateRangeProperty, new DateTimeRange(DateTime.MinValue, DateTime.MaxValue));
```